# Codeigniter Database Insert Failure

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, insert

Currently in my controller, when adding new data, I validate the inputs, and if there are any problems it lets a user known, otherwise it passes the data to the model to insert to the database

How do I now go about checking the insert statement worked correctly in the model, and let a user known if it did not.

Does an insert statement like below, return true or false, which can then be returned to the controller?

```
$this->db->insert('Faviroute_Addresses', $address_data);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use

```
if($this->db->insert('Faviroute_Addresses', $address_data))
{
    // Code here after successful insert
    return true;   // to the controller
}
```

Or you can use

```
$this->db->insert('Faviroute_Addresses', $address_data);
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
{
    // Code here after successful insert
    return true; // to the controller
}
```

Comment: one thing to note that i've come across recently is if you are using $this->db->affected_rows() for UPDATE queries, it will return a zero if the query succeeded but no information was changed from what already existed in the row.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd avoid using the

```
$this->db->affected_rows()
```

method for an insert. SQLServer doesn't return a value for an insert, so taking the return value from

```
$this->db->insert(...)
```

would be more reliable. I'd reserve affected_rows for checking "UPDATE"s  :)

**UPDATE:**

The same thing applies for

```
$this->db->delete()
```

The affected_rows() function doesn't work in SQL Server on a delete...